# Executor Service force all threads to run

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I have a `fixed thread pool` with a size of (let's say) 5. I also have a `blocking queue` which contains a number of `Objects` that the threads need to interact with.

Having about 50-100 objects, only one thread actually starts and does all the work. Is this expected? Can I force all 5 threads to start / pick up the Objects from the queue?

---

I can provide some sample code if required.

---

I had another mistake in my code, everything is sorted now :)

Comment: "I can provide some sample code if required." Yes.

Comment: can you provide your sample code.

Comment: I dont think, issue would be with Executor service. It is used by community since long. It would be great if you can check, if threads are started or init-ed but blocked due to some other reasons for example, usage of blocking queue etc.

Comment: Reason was even though I was creating a pool thread with size 5, I was only starting 1 worker ... fixed it, works fine now